# Easy way of using STL algorithms in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code on Win32:

```
Actor* Scene::GetActor(const char* name)
{
    StringID actorID(name);

    auto actor = find_if(m_actors.begin(), m_actors.end(), [&](Actor* actor){return actor->GetName() == actorID;});
    return  actor != m_actors.end() ? *actor : NULL;
}
```

Because this couldn't be compiled on iPhone with GCC/LLVM Clang I want to removed C++11 features from it. Is there any other easy way of using STL algorithms without using C++11 features? I don't want to declare simple function like this compare function everywhere in the code.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question (I'll leave that for someone else), but if you're doing lookups often, perhaps you want a different data structure, like `std::map`.

Comment: Should we suppose that `m_actors` is something like `std::vector<Actor*>` (it seems so) ?

Comment: Have you tried with Xcode 4.2, which contains Apple LLVM 3.0?

Comment: @trojanfoe/@Roland Illig With LLVM 3.0 with C++0x enabled I have: Parsing error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to implement a generic predicate for this, something along these lines (demo [here](http://ideone.com/bovgb)):

```
template<class C, class T, T (C::*func)() const>
class AttributeEquals {
public:
    AttributeEquals(const T& value) : value(value) {}

    bool operator()(const C& instance) {
        return (instance.*func)() == value;
    }
private:
    const T& value;
};
```

This would require some more tweaking, since in your case you are working with pointers, but you get the general idea.

Comment: In a similar vein, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174115/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-by-a-property-of-the-object/5174694#5174694

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using Blocks?

```
auto actor = find_if(m_actors.begin(), m_actors.end(),
                     ^(Actor* actor){return actor->GetName() == actorID;});
```

Comment: No, but I will try. +1 for this

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an anonymous function, you'll have to define and construct a functor. You'll also have to drop the auto keyword.

```
Actor* Scene::GetActor(const char* name)
{
    StringID actorID(name);
    MyFunctor funct(actorID); // move code from anon function to operator() of MyFunctor
    // Replace InputIterator with something appropriate - might use a shortening typedef
    InputIterator actor = find_if(m_actors.begin(), m_actors.end(), funct);
    return  actor != m_actors.end() ? *actor : NULL;
}
```

If StringID is your own class, you can make it a functor by defining operator().