# Universal function pointer

Tags: c++, types, getter

There is some class which have methods like:

```
int getSomething1();
std::string getSomething2();
someClass getSomething3();
```

There is structure which describes fields of this class like:

```
{"name of field", pointer to getter, std::type_info}
```

Then I would like to use it as follows:

```
if(type == int){
   field_int = (int)getter();
}
else if(type == std::string){
   field_string = (std::string)getter();
}
etc.
```

How to transform getters like

```
 int getSomething1();
 std::string getSomething2();
 etc.
```

to some universal function pointer and then to get the correct value of field?

Comment: I think, template metaprogramming is the solution!

Comment: Do you want to detect this at compile time or at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683868/easy-way-of-using-stl-algorithms-in-c/7684035#7684035) of mine to another question addresses your problem pretty well. With some minor modifications, you get this:

```
template<class C, class T>
T get_attribute(const C& instance, T (C::*func)() const) {
    return (instance.*func)();
}
```

Assuming the following:

```
struct Foo {
    int getSomething1() const;
    std::string getSomething2() const;
    someClass getSomething3() const;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
Foo foo;
int value = get_attribute<Foo, int>(foo, &Foo::getSomething1);
std::string value = get_attribute<Foo, std::string>(foo,  &Foo::getSomething2);
someClass value = get_attribute<Foo, someClass>(foo,  &Foo::getSomething3);
```

You can of course transform `get_attribute` to a functor to bind some or all of the arguments.

Comment: I think it's a little bit more complicated than that - from the question, the OP is holding a secondary structure where these "pointer_to_something"s should be stored..

Comment: @Nim: Yeah, I just got that. I have modified it accordingly, and it should work fine.

Comment: @Nim The real problem here is that he wants to select the function dynamically.  Whether the function itself is a template or not doesn't really change anything in this regard.  (As written, the template looks like extra verbiage; it doesn't seem to do anything concrete except increase the number of lines of code.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be better achieved with already existing containers such as a [boost fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) sequence. I'd advice that you try this first.

Comment: @Bjorn, thx - I normally just use the latest release - but that link is better...

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal universal function pointer, the equivalent of `void*`
for data.  The usual solution is to use `void (*)()`; you are guaranteed
that you can convert any (non-member) function pointer to this (or any
other function pointer type) and back without loss of information.

If there is a certain similarity in the function signatures (e.g. all
are getters, with no arguments) and how they are used, it may be
possible to handle this with an abstract base class and a set of derived
classes (possibly templated); putting pointers to instances of these
classes in a map would definitely be more elegant than an enormous
switch.

Answer (score 0):

Templates to the rescue!

```
// Create mapping of type to specific function
template <typename T> T getSomething(); // No default implementation
template <> int getSomething<int>() { return getSomething1(); } 
template <> std::string getSomething<std::string>() { return getSomething2(); }
template <> someClass getSomething<someClass>() { return getSomething3(); }
// Convenience wrapper
template <typename T> void getSomething(T& t) { t = getSomething<T>(); }
// Use
int i = getSomething<int>();
std::string s;
getSomething(s);
```

Comment: What does the template buy us here (except extra lines of code)?  (I can see using the template if you want to wrap the call in some sort of class.  But I'd need to know more about his actual use to be able to say what might be appropriate in such a case.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your difficulty is in storing the function pointers, since they are of different types. You can solve this using [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) and [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function.html).

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

int getInt() {
    return 0;  
}

std::string getString() {
    return "hello";
}

int main()
{
    boost::function<boost::any ()> intFunc(getInt);
    boost::function<boost::any ()> strFunc(getString);

    int i = boost::any_cast<int>(intFunc());
    std::string str = boost::any_cast<std::string>(strFunc());
}
```