# How to retrieve a field array from an object array?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a vector of objects by a property of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174115/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-by-a-property-of-the-object)

I have a structure like below:

```
strcut Point
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};
```

I also have a generic sorting function for integers:

```
void sort(vector<int>);
```

In my program, I need to sort an array of points std::vector frequently using different fields (i.e. x, y, or z). What can I do to convert an array of Points into an an array of integers efficiently?

Comment: Am I correct in saying you want to either sort by x value, y value, or z value? If so, use `std::sort` with your own predicate.